# Python: Indexing a string with specific conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help with this:
**Find the number of words that contain none of the five vowels and three y's.**

So far, I have:

```
def no_vowels_yyy(s):
        count = 0
        list_of_vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
        for i in range(0, len(s)):
                if s[i] not in list_of_vowels and (s[i] == 'y') == 3:
                        return True
        return False
```

This is not working though...

Comment: For future reference, when asking a question, rather than just saying "it is not working", you should specify _what_ is not working. For example, is it raising an error message? Are you giving it some input, but the output is not what you expect (and if so, what is this input/output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly different solution.

First, we build a `set` of vowels.  It is very fast to check if a particular character is in this set, or not; faster than checking in a list.  Also, we build it once, outside the function, instead of building it every time the function is called.

We use `any()` with a generator expression that checks each character to see if it is in the set.  If any character is in the set of vowels, we return False.

Next, we use `sum()` with a generator expression to count how many `'y'` characters there are; for each character that is a `'y'`, the value `1` is added by the `sum()` function.  We return whether this result is 3.

This will be a bit faster than looping over the string with an index and updating a counter variable.  This is more of a "Pythonic" solution.  On the other hand, this loops over the string twice rather than once.

```
_vowels = set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])

def no_vowels_yyy(s):
    if any(ch in _vowels for ch in s):
        return False

    return s.count('y') == 3

print(no_vowels_yyy("zyzyxy"))
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `sum` rather than `str.count`? It seems exactly the same to me except more typing and probably a tiny bit slower.

Comment: for a string of 5 characters a linear search: `ch in "aeiou"` should be faster. With a set you could check intersection: `_vowels.isdisjoint(s)`. [Putting it together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15052427/4279).

Comment: @Dougal, I forgot about `str.count()` but now that you and J.F. Sebastian have brought it to my attention, I agree that it is the better way to do it.  The `sum(1 for some_generator_expression)` is a good trick to know, but when there is a built-in, by all means we should just use it!

Comment: I've tried [a simple benchmark](http://ideone.com/wzsC9H). There is no difference between `ch in _vowels` and `ch in "aeiou"` in this case. `.isdisjoint()` is several times faster.

Comment: I love it how you can just copy someone else's answer and get the accept.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen, sorry you seem to have your feelings hurt.  I promise you I don't copy from others, except when I do so and provide credit (I say something like "this is Xyz's answer but with XXXX difference").  I don't remember this one, but what often happens is that I spend a lot of time editing, and while I am editing someone else posts something similar.  Note that I put more explanation than you did, and perhaps the answer was accepted partly due to the explanation.  Also, if I were copying, I would have copied your use of the `.count()` method function!

Comment: @steveha I was just scrolling through my answers and this was like the third one which copied my method. As far as I can see, you ARE using my `.count()` method and you edited it in Feb 25 while I posted mine in Feb 24. But yes you deserve the accept cause of your explanation.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen, please read through all the comments.  You will see one from "Dougal" on Feb 24 asking why I wrote the code using `sum()` instead of simply using the `.count()` method, and you will see my comment saying essentially "oh right thanks, that was silly of me so I changed it" (date: Feb 25).  Really, I didn't copy your answer, not even on Feb 25.  Also you can look at the edit history and verify that I originally wrote the code differently.  If you have any further questions, please use the chat feature so that we don't clutter up the question page with back-and-forth discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Your check for the number of y's `(s[i] == 'y') == 3:` is what's causing it not to work. Comparing `s[i]` to `'y'` will give you a boolean (true/false) result, not the number of matches. Since you are looping through, you could just keep a count of the number of y's you've found.

```
def no_vowels_yyy(s):
    count = 0
    list_of_vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
            if s[i] in list_of_vowels:
                return False
            if s[i] == 'y':
                count += 1

    return count == 3
```

Comment: What does: return count == 3 do?

Comment: Returns True is count is 3, else False.

Comment: I am still getting 'count' equals to 0

Comment: Python does not have the `++` operator.  In Python, use `count += 1` to increment `count` by one.

Comment: I noticed it didn't have the count++ and changed it, but it still gave me the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since others have already told you what's the problem, I'll just offer a solution of my own. This is probably the best way, I can't see why not to use `string.count()`-method:

```
def no_vowels_yyy(s):
    if any(c in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'} for c in s):
        return False
    return s.count('y') == 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show another way...:

```
from collections import Counter
def func(text):
    freq = Counter(text)
    return freq['y'] == 3 and not (freq.viewkeys() & 'aeiou')
```

Has the advantage of just one parse, but doesn't short circuit on vowels...

Otherwise, to short circuit as soon as possible:

```
y_count = 0
for ch in word:
    if ch in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}:
        return False
    elif ch == 'Y':
        y_count += 1
        if y_count > 3:
            return False
return y_count == 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def no_vowels_yyy(s, _vowels=set("aeiou")):
    return s.count("y") == 3 and _vowels.isdisjoint(s)
print(no_vowels_yyy("zyzyxy")) # -> True
```

Or a more readable version:

```
def no_vowels_yyy(s):
    return s.count("y") == 3 and all(c not in "aeiou" for c in s)
```

Comment: I really like `s.count('y') == 3`.  Way better than `sum()` with a generator expression!